# How do I select specific cells into a Java grid GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, grid-layout

I'm developing a GUI grid and I need to select specific cells. I used `JFrame`. My goal is to fulfill the first column and the last row with numbers, like `x-y` axes.

**I have tried** to declare an array of `JButtons` with the exact cell position that I need, setting the text. (The caps-lock comment in code)

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridLayoutTest {

    private static JButton[] arrayBtn;

    public static void main(String[] args ) {

        // the frame that contains the components
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayoutTest from JCG");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // set the size of the frame
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);

        // set the rows and cols of the grid, as well the distances 
       between them
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(10,14, 0, 0);
        // what layout we want to use for our frame
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);;
        frame.setLayout(grid);

        arrayBtn = new JButton[140];

        // add JButtons dynamically
        for(int i=0; i < arrayBtn.length; i++) {
            arrayBtn[i] = new JButton();  

            arrayBtn[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            arrayBtn[i].setSize(1,1);

               //IF I RUN ONLY THIS WORKS WITH THE FIRST CELL(IF I INSERT OUT 
               // THE FOR CYCLE DOESN'T WORK)
               arrayBtn[0].setText("9");

              // IF I RUN ALSO THIS CODE ROW I HAVE THE SAME ERROR 
               arrayBtn[1].setText("9");



            frame.add(arrayBtn[i]);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
relative to the row of the specific cell selected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the second cell (index 1) during **every** loop iteration, which means even during the first iteration where the second cell is not initialized.

Let's say we enter the loop the first time. We are going to initialize the first button (index 0). Then you set the text of the second button (index 1) to `"9"`. This button has not been initialized yet, so we are calling a method on an object that is still `null`. That is the reason why you receive a `NullPointerException`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayBtn.length; i++) {
    arrayBtn[i] = new JButton();
    arrayBtn[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    arrayBtn[i].setSize(1, 1);

    // This works (set every button text to "9"):
    arrayBtn[i].setText("9");

    // This will NOT work:
    arrayBtn[1].setText("9"); 

    frame.add(arrayBtn[i]);
}

// This works (set the first button text to "9"):
arrayBtn[0].setText("9");
```

Keep in mind that array indexing starts with the index 0:

```
String[] array = {"first", "second", "third"};
System.out.println(array[1]); // will print "second"
```

So in the full context of your question: Maybe you should consider using a [two-dimensional array](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap49C/ch49C_3.html) for your array of buttons since that resembles more closely the grid you are trying to build (10x14).

```
JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[10][14];
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 14; x++) {
        buttonGrid[y][x] = new JButton("Test");
        if (y == 0) {
            // code in here is only executed for the first row
            buttonGrid[y][x].setText(Integer.toString(x));
        }
        if (x == 0) {
            // code in here is only executed for the first column
            buttonGrid[y][x].setText(Integer.toString(y));
        }
    }
}
```

This will look somewhat like this:

```
[0, 1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,    10,   11,   12,   13  ]
[1, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[2, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[3, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[4, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[5, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[6, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[7, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[8, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
[9, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With your solution I obtain the same value in all the cells. How can I have the value only in a specific cell?

Comment: I updated my answer. Keep in mind that if you want to set only one cell, you should do it outside of the loop, else the line will be executed for every loop iteration. And this is not necessary!

Comment: Thanks! I have seen the update. With only     arrayBtn[0].setText("9");     now works! But if I add also 
            arrayBtn[1].setText("9");     I obtain the same error of before. Do you know why?

Comment: You can only call methods on objects that have been initialized. If you call setText() on a JButton that has not been initialized with new JButton(), it will always generate a NullPointerException. Where did you call arrayBtn[1].setText("9") exactly? Inside the loop?

Comment: I have solved inserting those code rows after the for cycle! Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear! I updated my answer to give you some more information on how you could build a 2D grid of buttons!

Comment: Your great! Thanks